# EJB interface JNDI lookup

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb, jndi

i have an interface

```
@Local
public interface TestService extends Serializable
{
    public void aMethod();
}
```

a stateless bean that implements it

```
@Stateless
public class MyappServiceBean implements TestService
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void aMethod()
    {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

a managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
public class MyappBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    private TestService service;

    ...
}
```

and this POJO

```
public class TestPojo implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final TestService service;

    public TestPojo()
    {
        // this works
        // service = (TestService) InitialContext.doLookup("java:global/myapp/MyappServiceBean");

        // this works too
        // service = (TestService) InitialContext.doLookup("java:global/myapp/MyappServiceBean!com.example.common.ejb.TestService");

        // this works again
        // service = (TestService) InitialContext.doLookup("java:app/myapp/MyappServiceBean");

        // how to lookup ONLY by interface name/class ?
        service = (TestService) InitialContext.doLookup("???/TestService");
    }

    ...
}
```

everyting is packed:

```
myapp.war
    |   
    + WEB-INF
        |
        + lib
        |   |
        |   + common.jar
        |       |
        |       - com.example.common.ejb.TestService (@Local interface)
        |       |
        |       - com.example.common.util.TestPojo (simple pojo, must lookup)
        |
        + classes
            |
            - com.example.myapp.ejb.MyappServiceBean (@Stateless impl)
            |
            - com.example.myapp.jsf.MyappBean (jsf @ManagedBean)
```

since i want to use `common.jar` inside different applications, i want a lookup based on `Testservice` interface name, much like i inject `@EJB TestService service;` in `@ManagedBean` or `@WebServlet`

how to achieve this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why do you only want to look based on Interface class name? You said other look-ups work fine.

Comment: read last sentence of question :)

Comment: You can package your EJB as a separate jar file within your war instead of scattering classes across WEB-INF/classes and lib directories.

Comment: i don't need and don't want to package separately. and what has this to do with my question?

Answer (score 3):

a dirty solution is to declare

```
@Stateless(name = "TestService")
public class MyappServiceBean implements TestService
```

and lookup it from pojo:

```
service = (TestService) InitialContext.doLookup("java:module/TestService");
```

**any better solution will be happily accepted!**

Comment: I use the portable version of JNDI names, excerpt from logfile: `Portable JNDI names for EJB country: [java:global/jfinancials-ejb/country, java:global/jfinancials-ejb/country!org.mxchange.jcountry.model.data.CountrySingletonBeanRemote]]]` comes from my application. And in my WAR/EJB project: `@EJB (lookup = "java:global/jfinancials-ejb/country!org.mxchange.jcountry.model.data.CountrySingletonBeanRemote")`. By `CountrySingletonBeanRemote` is annotated with `@javax.ejb.Remote` and is the remote interface. And it is `lookup` not `doLookup`.

Comment: I use Payara here, then I have to copy "custom" JAR files to `personal_domain/lib/` folder in my home directory (under Linux, commonly `~/personal_domain/lib/` and then restart the whole application server to let it load the JAR file. Then it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Simple method:

```
    private MyappServiceBean getMyappServiceBean() {
    try {
        return InitialContext.doLookup("java:module/MyappServiceBean");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        logger.error("Failed to look up MyappServiceBean EJB", e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: -1: *i want a lookup based on Testservice interface name, much like i inject EJB TestService service; in ManagedBean or WebServlet*.